# Randomly named assemblies (.NET)

Tags: .net, exception

When a .NET application (in my case it's SQL Management Studio, but I think, it's more general issue) fails due to unhandled exception, I receive a popup with a call stack and a list of loaded assemblies.

Among them I see 2 or 3 randomly named assemblies, which in all other aspects look like copies of System.dll:

```
----------------------------------------
epovwbjf
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
l3kwu1p5
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
9wpjdbe7
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
```

Is this a normal behaviour or a sign of malware infection ? (I've tested that dll via virustotal.com, it detected 0/46). Why does it happen (if it's expected) and where can I learn more on it ?

Answer (score 1):

Those paths are to the system GAC, the Global Assembly Cache: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx

The value `b77a5c561934e089` is the public key token for the signed assembly System.dll.